# LibQxT does not detect Qt version properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, configure, libqxt

I am trying to install LibQxT to use it with Qt5, so I downloaded the sources and as soon as I run the configure.bat there is an error:

> LibQxt requires 4.3 or newer but Qt 5.2.1 was detected.

Searching on the web Ive found out that apparently it doesnt know the correct path to the qconfig.pri (as seen [here (last post)](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt-old-hg/issue/87/qxt-060-fails-to-configure-on-win7-with-qt)) so it doesnt really detect the version.

I have tried adding the path to the variable QTDIR in the ways described in the post
 (I tried to do it in the qmake cache located in the Libqxt folder and tried to define it as a environment variable). I havent found any clear solution to this problem, so I hope someone knows by now how to solve this issue.

Thankyou.

**EDIT**
What @vahancho said its true, if its not detecting the version, why does it name it? Perhaps its not detecting it properly.

 But if it is, why cant it see that my version is higher than the requested one?

I have located the error and it fails at some point betweeen the echos and the if:
    echo    Configuration successful.
    echo    Generating makefiles...
    cd %QXT_BUILD_TREE%
    %QMAKE_BIN% %MSVCMODE% -recursive %QXT_SOURCE_TREE%\libqxt.pro
    if errorlevel 1 goto mainqmakeERR

Comment: But how it says `but Qt 5.2.1 was detected.`, if it cannot detect the version?

Comment: @vahancho If it is detecting the version, how does it not realize that its a higher verison than 4.3?

Comment: I think it is simply not aware about Qt5 and its versions. Did you check the configure.bat file? What it does?

Comment: @vahancho it has around 365 lines and basically sets a lot of variables and such needed for configuring the installation and preparing makefiles. It must be something else, this problem has happened to other people with 4.x as well, and it has worked for people with Qt 5.

Comment: Try to use the latest development branch which is libqxt 0.7

Comment: @Nejat I cannot seem to find a source for that branch, could you please provide one?

Comment: You can see the latest source code at http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src

Comment: You can just clone one for your self.

Comment: @Nejat It worked! Thankyou very much! And sorry, I was not very aware of what git was (newbie programmer here)

Comment: @Nejat please post it as an answer so people with a similar problem can find help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the latest development branch of libqxt which could be found [here](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/src). It will be compiled with Qt 5. You can just clone one copy of the source code by:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/libqxt/libqxt.git
```